# Blogger - expanding/collapsing Comment Form not working

Tags: blogger

I've followed a tutorial i found online to implement a expand/collapse script which affects the comment form on a blogger blog.

I have implemented it on a testing blog in order to see if i encounter any issues, and i did, 2 of them. So i tried resolving them, but failed to figure it out.

One is the fact that the widget doesn't work on a post that has comments. If there is even one comment on a post it won't work.

The other is the fact that when i open the blog in chrome the pager links (previous/newest/home) are not visible.

Here is my test blog, a page with comments: http://testingtestingblogblognow.blogspot.com/2013/09/test-post-1.html

Open any other post to see a post without comments where the widget works perfectly.

Here is the tutorial i used to implement this, you can see the Javascript and CSS codes here: http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2012/06/expandcollapse-blogger-comment-box-with.html

I know this can be fixed because i've seen this widget working perfectly on other blogs.

Note: I was going to include the codes i used here, but i thought it would clutter the post too much. If it will make it easier tell me and i'll include the codes i used here.

Hope someone helps me out. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Also when I click on the reply hyperlink it opens a black new tab anyway you could try some other comment systems.

My suggestions : 
http://www.spiceupyourblog.com/2013/12/new-unique-css-comment-design-for-blogger.html

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/3rdparty-comment-discuss-systems-reviewed/

Comment: Thanks Shim.

The first link you provided has to do with the Comment Boxes, not the comment form at all...

And the second link has to do with other commenting systems entirely, not the blogger one...

Anyway, thanks for looking into it. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can find here all widget codes and css style codes and password protect codes http://www.abcinformer.blogspot.com

Comment: Consider posting this as a comment, or at least give some code in your answer, instead of posting a link-only answer. The link might rot and your answer might become invalid.